# Highlight changes in code since last commit in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, diff

Is there any way I can show changes that I made since the last commit in the code editor?

Answer (score 14):

Use the **Version Control** tab.  Under **Log**, you can select the first two changes, and use CTRL + D or Command + D to produce a diff between the two.

Note that this approach works best with code under source control that's registered with Android Studio.  If you're not using any source control, you can still get a partial history of changes by navigating to VCS > Local History > Show Local History and selecting the root directory in your project.  Note that this is subject to the Local History log length, which is nominally limited to 1,000 entries.

Answer (score 9):

On the left side of IDE open "Project" bar and select "Changed Files"

[image]

Answer (score 9):

If you are using subversion **Git** then :

**VCS->Git->Compare with the Same Repository Version**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the menu:

**VCS -> Subversion -> Compare with lastest repository version**